# awk: Interpreting strings as mathematical expressions

Tags: shell, awk

**Context:** I have an input file that contains parameters with associated values followed by literal mathematical expressions such as:

```
PARAMETERS DEFINITION
A = 5; B = 2; C=1.5; D=7.5

MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSIONS
A*B
C/D
...
```

and I would like to get the strings of the second part to be interpreted as mathematical expressions so that I get the results of the expressions in my output file:

```
...
MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSIONS
10
0.2
...
```

**What I did already:** So far, using awk, I store all the parameters names and their corresponding values in two distinct arrays. I then replace each parameter with its value so that I am now in a similar situation as the author of [this thread](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/232839-awk-evaluating-string-math-expression.html). 
However, the answers s/he gets are not in awk except for the last one which is very specific to her/his situation, and hard to understand for me as a beginner with awk and shell scripting.

**What I tried afterwards:** As I have no clue how to do this in awk, the idea I had was to store the new field value in a variable, then use a shell command within the awk script like this:

```
#!bin/awk -f
BEGIN{}
{ 
myExpression=$1
system("echo $myExpression | bc")
}
END{}
```

This, unfortunately does not work as the variable  is somehow not recognized by the echo command.

**What I would like:**
I would prefer a solution using awk alone with no call to external functions, however, I am not against one using a shell command if it is simpler.

**EDIT** Taking into account all the comments so far, I will be more precise, my input files look more like this:

```
PARAMETERS_DEFINITION
[param1] = 5
[param2] = 2
[param3] = 1.5
[param4] = 7.5

MATHEMATICAL_EXPRESSIONS
[param1]*[param2]
some text containing also numbers and formulas that I do not want to be affected. 
e.g: 1.45*2.6 = x, de(x)/dx=e(x) ; blah,blah,blah
[param3]/[param4]
```

The names of the parameters are complex enough so that any match of the string: `"[param#]"` within the document corresponds to a parameter that I want changed for its value.

Below is the way I manage to store the parameters and their value in arrays is the following:

```
{   
if (match($2,/PARAMETERS_DEFINITION/) != 0) {paramSwitch = 1}
if (match($2,/MATHEMATICAL_EXPRESSIONS/) != 0) {paramSwitch = 0} 

if (paramSwitch == 1)
{
parameterName[numOfParam] = $1 ;  
parameterVal[numOfParam] = $3 ;     
numOfParam += 1
}
}
```

Comment: How are you storing the parameter names in an array ? Also is there only one line of parameter definitions ?

Comment: @Jidder : I will start with your second question: no, actually, there is one parameter per line, more like this: 
`A = 5 ...` with spaces around the equal signs. I take advantage of this to store the appropriate field in <arrayName[i]> and <arrayValue[i]> in a for loop incrementing <i> until I encounter the <MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSION> line. Is that clear enough?

Comment: Could you please put an example in your question for clarification please ?

Comment: "some text containing also numbers and formulas that I do not want to be affected." quite unhelpful. Post real input

Comment: @Jidder: I edited the post to include what you required

Comment: @confused00: I added an example line in the file so that you can get what I meant.
Sorry if this question looks that long but I had tried to follow the stack exchange recommendations to make my question as general as possible and to simplify the situation. I guess I simplified it a bit too much in the first place.

Comment: @Mary what differentiates between a line you want executing and the line you don't ? Is it if the line does not contain the param name ?

Comment: @Jidder exactly, in my 2nd edit, I stated that the parameters names were complex enough to be matched only where needed (that's why I put them in square brackets: these can be part of the name and ensure that the parameters names are not encountered anywhere else). I will comment your answer, I just need some more time to digest it.

Comment: @Mary I'll add an explanation later when i add brackets :)

Comment: @Mary you should really give a real exemple input, here the computation involved are simple, is it really the case or not ? For more help, what are the languages available on the target system ? maybe there's one more adapted to this kind of work (like perl or ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BIDMAS as a basis i have created this mathematical function in awk
I have not included brackets(or indices) yet as they will require some extra effort but i may add them later
This awk script effectively works as bc does.
No system call required, all in awk.

## Generic version for all applications

```
awk '{split($0,a,"+")
            for(i in a){
            split(a[i],s,"-")
            for(j in s){
                    split(s[j],m,"*")
                    for(k in m){
                            split(m[k],d,"/")
                            for(l in d){
                                    if(l>1)d[1]=d[1]/d[l]
                            }
                            m[k]=d[1]
                            delete d
                            if(k>1)m[1]=m[1]*m[k]
                    }
                    s[j]=m[1]
                    delete m
                    if(j>1)s[1]=s[1]-s[j]
            }
            a[i]=s[1]
            delete s
    }
            for(i in a)b=b+a[i];print b}{b=0}' file
```

## For your specific example

```
awk '
/MATHEMATICAL_EXPRESSIONS/{z=1}
NR>1&&!z{split($0,y," = ");x[y[1]]=y[2]}

z&&/[\+\-\/\*]/{
    for (n in x)gsub(n,x[n])
    split($0,a,"+")
        for(i in a){
                split(a[i],s,"-")
                for(j in s){
                        split(s[j],m,"*")
                        for(k in m){
                                split(m[k],d,"/")
                                for(l in d){
                                        if(l>1)d[1]=d[1]/d[l]
                                }
                                m[k]=d[1]
                                delete d
                                if(k>1)m[1]=m[1]*m[k]
                        }
                        s[j]=m[1]
                        delete m
                        if(j>1)s[1]=s[1]-s[j]
                }
                a[i]=s[1]
                delete s
        }
                for(i in a)b=b+a[i];print b}{b=0}' file
```

Comment: What if it uses `(sqrt(e^3.543)%3i)/4.5(43)`?

Comment: @confused00 I clearly state at the start i haven't included brackets, i also meant to add i haven't yet added indices. No need to post a ridiculous equation because you weren't happy with my comment.

Comment: Point was that it's an arbitrary line the 'how far to go and what assumptions to make' and I just made my solution to fit OP's input and explanations

Comment: @Mary Yes that will work for every operator you want(such as indices), except for the brackets. Brackets will need a slightly different approach.I was thinking of using a match statement and making the function recursive. I don't have time at the moment though but i will try to add this later

Comment: @confused00 Point is, is that your answer is so specific to the question and taking everything as literal input that it is of no use to anyone except OP and only for this specific case, and looking at the comment on your answer it isn't even fit for that.

Comment: my question was intended to answer OP's question, not solve all world's problems; and it doesn't work for the updated requirements cause I cba to update every time OP remembers something. bye

Comment: @confused00: I just tried to follow the advices of how to post a good question by making it general and simple. When I posted my first questions, I had put A, B, C and D for parameters, but I had in mind arbitrary strings, that was not clear and I realize it now. It is my first question here (and ever on any forum I think as I usually find my quesions already answered), so sorry for doing it wrong. But that's why the edits exist, isn't it?

Comment: @Mary , your question is fine,confused00 is just having a tantrum because he can't take any criticism. I have upvoted your question anyway as there doesn't seem to be a similar question for evaluating equations using awk on SO.

Comment: I looked at your solution more in depth, I did not try it but I see how it works. It is quite tedious, however, I think that I found another way, much easier, all in awk. I am just not sure yet, but that is just to warn you not to spend too much time on improving your answer :)

Comment: @Mary Which other way have you found? It would be interesting to see a different way this could be done :)

Comment: nevermind, I tried something with printf, I thought it would be easier, but finally I need to split everything just like you do, so its not an improvement. I believe your way is the simplest way although quite long. Tensibai was right and awk is not designed for that kind of task. Probably that perl would be more adequate for it, but as I discovered shell scripting a week ago, awk and sed 5 days ago, and now have I just read about perl, I could not really plan it to be that difficult. More generally, I find it hard to decide what language is the best suited for a task before trying code it.

Comment: @Mary Bit of a late reply, but if you don't know what language would be best to solve a problem then simply searching in google is always a good place to start. Searching `math utilities bash` reveals multiple links to `bc` which as stated by others on this post is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
{ 
  myExpression=$1
  system("echo $myExpression | bc")
}
```

I think you'd want this:

```
{ 
  myExpression=$1
  system("echo " myExpression " | bc")
}
```

That's because in awk, assignments do not end up as environment variables, and putting strings next to each other concatenates them.

Comment: That is very much helpful indeed, thank you very much. I will credit you the answer if no one comes out with an awk alone based solution.

Answer (score 1):

You asking *awk: Interpreting strings as mathematical expressions* - this functionality usually called as `eval`, and no, (AFAIK) `awk` doesn't knows such function. Therefore your questions is an typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

The right tool for this is `bc`, where you (nearly) don't need modify anything, and simply feed the `bc` with your input, only ensure than the variables are are lowercase, such the following input (edited the your example)

```
#PARAMETERS DEFINITION
a=5; b=2; c=1.5; d=7.5

#MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSIONS
a*b
c/d
```

using like

```
bc -l < inputfile
```

produces

```
10
.20000000000000000000
```

### EDIT

For your edit, for the new input data. The following

```
grep '\[' inputfile | sed 's/[][]//g' | bc -l
```

for the input

```
PARAMETERS_DEFINITION
[param1] = 5
[param2] = 2
[param3] = 1.5
[param4] = 7.5

MATHEMATICAL_EXPRESSIONS
[param1]*[param2]
some text containing also numbers and formulas that I do not want to be affected. 
e.g: 1.45*2.6 = x, de(x)/dx=e(x) ; blah,blah,blah
[param3]/[param4]
```

produces the following output:

```
10
.20000000000000000000
```

e.g. grepping out only lines what contains `[` - any param definition or expression, remove any `[]`, e.g. creating the following `bc` program:

```
param1 = 5
param2 = 2
param3 = 1.5
param4 = 7.5
param1*param2
param3/param4
```

and send the whole "program" to `bc`...

Comment: I think that you are wrong by stating that I fell into the XY problem trap as I started with the problem in itself. Only afterwards did I explain how I tried to solve it.

Comment: @Mary i write about the XY before you edit your question. Simply, if you asking the wrong (not fully defined) question, got a wrong answer. ;) Anyway, I'm still sure than the: 1.) convert your input into BC program 2.) calculate the expressions with BC (as a whole - not line-by-line) is the easiest way... - see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat test
PARAMETERS DEFINITION
A=5; B=2; C=1.5; D=7.5

MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSIONS
A*B
C/D
$ awk -vRS='[= ;\n]' '{if ($0 ~ /[0-9]/){a[x] = $0; print x"="a[x]}else{x=$0}}/MATHEMATICAL/{print "MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSIONS"}{if ($0~"*") print a[substr($0,1,1)] * a[substr($0,3,1)]}{if ($0~"/") print a[substr($0,1,1)] / a[substr($0,3,1)]}' test
A=5
B=2
C=1.5
D=7.5

MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSIONS
10
0.2
```

**Formatted nicely:**

```
$ cat test.awk
# Store all variables in an array
{ 
  if ($0 ~ /[0-9]/){
    a[x] = $0; 
    print x " = " a[x] # Print the keys & values
  }
  else{
   x = $0
  }
}
# Print header
/MATHEMATICAL/ {print "MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSIONS"}

# Do the maths (case can work too, but it's not as widely available)
{ 
  if ($0~"*") 
     print a[substr($0,1,1)] * a[substr($0,3,1)]
}

{
  if ($0~"/") 
     print a[substr($0,1,1)] / a[substr($0,3,1)]
}

{
  if ($0~"+") 
     print a[substr($0,1,1)] + a[substr($0,3,1)]
}

{
  if ($0~"-") 
     print a[substr($0,1,1)] - a[substr($0,3,1)]
}
$ cat test
PARAMETERS DEFINITION
A=5; B=2; C=1.5; D=7.5

MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSIONS
A*B
C/D
D+C
C-A

$ awk -f test.awk -vRS='[= ;\n]' test
A = 5
B = 2
C = 1.5
D = 7.5
MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSIONS
10
0.2
9
-3.5
```

Comment: What if it uses two operators ? `A+B-C`

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution, it is inspiring. However, it is not versatile enough and won't apply in my case (see the edit to the initial question). Also it presents the drawback mentionned by Jidder. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's something like an eval for awk, its a magical conversion when needed in the context, here adding +0 would do the convertion.

What I got for you (detailled version below) with a file named awkinput with your exemple input

`awk '/[A-Z]=[0-9.]+;/ { for (i=1;i<=NF ;i++) { print "working on "$i; split($i,fields,"="); sub(/;/,"",fields[2]); params[fields[1]]=strtonum(fields[2]) } }; /[A-Z](*|\/|+|-)[A-Z]/ { for (p in params) { sub(p, params[p],$0); }; system("echo " $0 " | bc -ql") }' awkinput`

Detailled:

```
/[A-Z]=[0-9.]+;?/ { # if we match something like A=4.2 with or wothout a ; at end
  for (i=1;i<=NF ;i++) { # loop through the fields (separated by space, the default Field Separator of awk)
    print "working on "$i; # inform on what we do
    split($i,fields,"="); # split in an array to get param and value
    sub(/;/,"",fields[2]); # Eventually remove the ; at end
    params[fields[1]]=strtonum(fields[2]) # new array of parameters where the values are numeric
  }
}
 /[A-Z](*|\/|+|-)[A-Z]/ { #when the line match a math operation with one param on each side (at least)
  for (p in params) { # loop over know params
    sub(p, params[p],$0); # replace each param with its value
  }; 
   system("echo " $0 " | bc -ql") # print the result (no way to get of system call here)
}
```

Drawback:

A math of the form `AB*C` would be resolved to `52*1.5`

Comment: Thank you for this, the first part (memorization of parameters) is quite different, and your way looks more robust than mine. For the second part (replacement of the names by the values), it looks quite like what I did.

Comment: Indeed, it was just an help around your question with some details to help implement. Sounds like you're shaving a Yack here with the wrong tool